# Django object not count

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-templates

when user adds items, number of items should appear in the dashboard but my code does not count however it is only showing zero here what i have tried so far.

**views.py**

```
class ItemListView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    model = Item
    template_name = 'item/items.html'
    context_object_name = 'items'
    ordering = ['-created_at', '-updated_at']

    def get_queryset(self):
        return super(ItemListView, self).get_queryset().filter(author=self.request.user)

class ItemCountView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    model = Item
    template_name = 'dashboard/dash.html'
    context_object_name = 'items'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Item.objects.filter(author=self.request.user)
```

**in templates dash.html**

when it is `{{ items.count }}` it does not count but if `{{ items|length }}` it shows zero. Please show me where i am making mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `count()` in queryset

```
def get_queryset(self):
    return Item.objects.filter(author=self.request.user).count()
```

Then in templates use `{{ items }}`

Update:

```
class ItemListView(LoginRequiredMixin, View):
    template_name = 'item/items.html'
    login_url = 'accounts/login/'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        total_item = Item.objects.filter(author=self.request.user).count()
        context = {'total_item': total_item}
        return render(request, self.template_name, context)
```

In template use `{{ total_item }}`

**Update 2:**

```
class ItemCountView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    model = Item
    template_name = 'dashboard/dash.html'
    context_object_name = 'items'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Item.objects.all().values('item_name').annotate(total=Count('item_name'))
```

Then in template use

```
{% for item in items %}
    {{ item.item_name }} {{ item.total }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: wow it is super!! @shafik i am sorry i made you bother for some time it is finally working but one thing i wonder thing item counting is only one feature of dashboard if i want to add another functionalities to it, should I add more urls to dashboard?

Comment: No. You can use `get_context_data`. Study this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/#adding-extra-context. This may help you. Another url doesn't solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

You can define property in Item model:

```
class Item(models.Model):

    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    @property
    def count(self):
        self.__class__.objects.filter(author=self.request.user).count()
```

No changes in templates required. Also queryset in view does not needed anymore

Comment: you already call {{ items.count }} in your template. My version for this case.
when {{ items.count }} appears in template @property will be called

Comment: even with `__class__`?
you add it into **model**?